# add/remove fields and relationships to an existing entity Jhipster

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, liquibase, gradlew, jhipster-registry

I am using jhipster (jhipsterVersion -> 4.11.1),
I have created Student entity through  "yo jhipster:entity" student and add fields like rollNo,name,course.
after that run gradlew commad to run application so far everything is working fine, entity is created successful with given proper field.

But after 1 days I required to add new field like collegeName and i ran  "yo jhipster:entity student" command again and add one more field  collegeName  and to got message built successful but when i run gradlew command to run application I got error like Below

---

2017-12-28 15:08:04.442 ERROR 5268 --- [tapp-Executor-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   :
Liquibase could not start correctly, your database is NOT ready: Validation Failed:
     1 change sets check sum
          config/liquibase/changelog/20171228063150_added_entity_Student.xml::20171228063150-1::jhip
ster was: 7:1e76a424cb8d1fd8f33d27559cee9133 but is now: 7:a69d676fb7b3d1b37c22d109340b7c2b

liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
     1 change sets check sum
          config/liquibase/changelog/20171228063150_added_entity_Student.xml::20171228063150-1::jhip
ster was: 7:1e76a424cb8d1fd8f33d27559cee9133 but is now: 7:a69d676fb7b3d1b37c22d109340b7c2b

```
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.validate(DatabaseChangeLog.java:266)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:210)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:431)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:388)

    at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.initDb(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java
```

:82)
        at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$0(Asyn
cSpringLiquibase.java:64)
        at io.github.jhipster.async.ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.lambda$createWrappedRunnable$
1(ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.java:66)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2017-12-28 15:08:14.169  INFO 5268 --- [  restartedMain] com.quote.TestappApp                     :
Started TestappApp in 26.25 seconds (JVM running for 27.304)

### 2017-12-28 15:08:14.171  INFO 5268 --- [  restartedMain] com.quote.TestappApp                     :

Comment: If I add/remove fields and relationships to an existing entity through commands then  should I generate change log by " gradlew liquibaseDiffChangelog " command and generated change log file  to your src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml file  myself manually or  All the task will completed automatically ?

Comment: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/6176

Answer (score 0):

Please run the below command in terminal
./mvnw liquibase:clearCheckSums